# Как отследить выполнение условия при перезагрузке страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Приветствую. Есть интернет-витрина с корзиной, в которую добавляются товары. При удалении позиции, по клику remove происходит удаление элемента как положено, но после этого сама страница перезагружается и не отрабатывает уже условие внутри клика if ($(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li").hasClass("empty")) {}
т.е. это блок в котором находятся удаляемые элементы и по умолчанию, когда в нем ничего нет кроме div с классом empty он скрыт. А вот когда он есть -в нем находятся уже элементы, которые можно удалить, но проблема в том, что после удаления любого элемента страница перезагружается и блок снова скрывается, хотя из условия должен отображается, т.к. он не пустой.

```js
$(".remove-item").click(function() {
  if ($(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li").hasClass("empty")) {
    $(".fixed-bottom").hide();
  } else {
    $('#foot-carousel').data('owlCarousel').removeItem($(this));
    $(".fixed-bottom").show();
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item" style="width: 315px;">
      <div class="li">
        <a href="#">
          <img width="60" height="60" src="#" class="attachment-60x60 wp-post-image" alt="item-4">
        </a>

        <div class="product-text">
          <div class="product-name">Название</div>
          <span class="quantity">13 × <span class="amount">120,000&nbsp;руб.</span></span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-quantity">
       <a href="#" class="remove-item" title="Удалить эту позицию">remove</a>      </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не перезагружайте страницу. Используйте ajax

Comment: @ArchDemon в каком смысле использовать ajax?- поясните.вот страница с темой - [http://velikorodnov.com/wordpress/flatastic/classic/] - можете увидеть демонстрацию, что страница сама перегружается, а
галочка напротив ajax стоит, если что [http://s017.radikal.ru/i430/1506/38/63553e8f4a3a.png]

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас элемент выполнен ссылкой, то нужно для начала отменить его действие по умолчанию. Для этого в функцию клика нужно передать само событие клика. `.click(function(e) {})` и потом сбросить его обработчик по умолчанию `e.preventDefault()`. После этого выполнится ваш код, но не произойдет перехода. Для перехода в нужном куске нужно будет вставить `window.location.href = ваш_адрес_для_перехода`. Так же рекомендую проверить обработчики, которые уже висят на этой кнопке. Возможно один из них обновляет страницу.

Comment: Сюда же (любой из вариантов). Можно так же в обработчике в конце добавить `return false;`. Можно в ссылку прописать такой href: `javascript: void(0)`.